# How does this code execute?

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I have a basic PlayerEntity which on update updates it's position using velocity. This is the whole update method:

```
public void update() {

    if (!AABB.checkCollisionCB(world, position[0] += velocity[0], position[1], position[2])) {
        //position[0] += velocity[0];
    }

    if (!AABB.checkCollisionCB(world, position[0], position[1] += velocity[1], position[2])) {
        //position[1] += velocity[1];
        }

    if (!AABB.checkCollisionCB(world, position[0], position[1], position[2] += velocity[2])) {
        //position[2] += velocity[2];
        }


    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        velocity[i] *= .8;
}
```

Now as you see, the position[0] += velocity[0]; is commented out, and in theory should not execute, but it still does! What is the deal with this? Also, if it still seems to execute when they are uncommented, and the 'if' isn't satisfied!

The only other mention of the PlayerEntity in code is the following:

```
    if (player.pushingF == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[0] += .05;
    if (player.pushingB == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[0] -= .05;

    if (player.pushingJ == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[1] += .05;
    if (player.pushingS == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[1] -= .05;

    if (player.pushingL == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[2] += .05;
    if (player.pushingR == true)
        playerEntity.velocity[2] -= .05;
```

But that only changes velocity, and shouldn't do anything position related.
I'm using eclipse, I tried 'Project > Clean,' but that seemed to do nothing.. Strangely enough it wont do any printing in the console, or perhaps any other functions from within those 'if's.

Comment: A big lesson I have learned while programming is - programs always do exactly what they are told. If they do something unexpected, it's merely that you are overlooking how it was told to do that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (!AABB.checkCollisionCB(world, position[0] += velocity[0], ...
```

Notice that you have `position[0] += velocity[0]` in the condition of your `if`-statement, and so it will execute regardless of whether or not the condition evaluates to `true` (and regardless of what the statement's body is).

Comment: Muh mane 5/5, I changed it to position[0] **+** velocity[0], ...

Answer (score 1):

You change your variable in if statement:

```
if (!AABB.checkCollisionCB(world, position[0] += velocity[0], position[1], position[2]))
```

It will always be changed if you do it that way...